# Why header status not changed?

Tags: php, header, status

Please before you mark it down tell me why first, thanks.
 I have this update code below which is works. However the header response is 304 not modified, but it clearly did. I tried to add  `header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK'); $time = time() - 60; header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', $time).' GMT');` just before the die(); but it doesn't work. I would like to show 200 status, modified time and possibly the name was changed in the string parameters.

```
if(isset($_POST['update'])) {

     $stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE details set name = :name                                                               
                            WHERE user_id = {$_SESSION['user_session']}");

     $stmt->bindValue(':name', $_POST[ 'name']);

     $stmt->execute();
     echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0">';
     die();
} //end of isset update
```

Comment: header should be called before any output (ie before echo), also header has 2nd argument and 3rd argument for this task

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Lashane, however after I put it before echo the status code still not changed. Sorry I am complete new to this.

Answer (score 0):

304 just means you're getting a cached page because nothing has changed, which makes sense since you're not outputting anything to the page with the update statement. You might check your web server configuration for cache settings, or simply echo out a time stamped success message if you really want to see a 200.

Comment: Hi @Jeff Puckett II  first of all Thank you.  The problem was I have changed the name and it was successfully changed in the database, however the header status was saying 304 not modified. So I am not sure why the header not showing the data changed code. I am not sure if should be 200 I think maybe should be 302? I just want to prove in the header the data has changed

Comment: The database has changed, but the web server's http response has no bearing on that. If you want to confirm, then echo out a response on the page to update the web page so the web server will serve a fresh page. Don't confuse web pages with database records. The http response has no bearing on database status.

Comment: Thank you very much @Jeff Puckett II